# Merge two dictionaries based on similarity excluding a key

Tags: python

I have the following three dictionaries in an array:

```
items = [ 
{
    'FirstName': 'David',
    'LastName': 'Smith',
    'Language': set(['en'])
},

{
    'FirstName': 'David',
    'LastName': 'Smith',
    'Language': set(['fr'])
},

{
    'FirstName': 'Bob',
    'LastName': 'Jones',
    'Language': set(['en'])
} ]
```

I want to merge together these dictionaries if the two dictionaries are the same minus the specified key: and add that key together. If using the `"Language"` key it would merge the array into the following:

```
[ {
    'FirstName': 'David',
    'LastName': 'Smith',
    'Language': set(['en','fr'])
},{
    'FirstName': 'Bob',
    'LastName': 'Jones',
    'Language': set(['en'])
} ]
```

Here is what I'm currently doing:

```
from copy import deepcopy

def _merge_items_on_field(items, field):
    '''Given an array of dicts, merge the 
       dicts together if they are the same except for the 'field'.

       If merging dicts, add the unique values of that field together.'''

    items = deepcopy(items)
    items_merged_on_field = []

    for num, item in enumerate(items):

        # Remove that key/value from the dict
        field_value = item.pop(field)

        # Get an array of items *without* that field to compare against
        items_without_field = deepcopy(items_merged_on_field)
        map(lambda d: d.pop(field), items_without_field)

        # If the dict item is found ("else"), add the fields together
        # If not ("except"), then add in the dict item to the array
        try:
            index = items_without_field.index(item) 
        except ValueError:
            item[field] = field_value
            items_merged_on_field.append(item)
        else:
            items_merged_on_field[index][field] = items_merged_on_field[index][field].union(field_value)

    return items_merged_on_field

>>> items = [{'LastName': 'Smith', 'Language': set(['en']), 'FirstName': 'David'}, {'LastName': 'Smith', 'Language': set(['fr']), 'FirstName': 'David'}, {'LastName': 'Jones', 'Language': set(['en']), 'FirstName': 'Bob'}]
>>> _merge_items_on_field(items, 'Language')
[{'LastName': 'Smith', 'Language': set(['fr', 'en']), 'FirstName': 'David'}, {'LastName': 'Jones', 'Language': set(['en']), 'FirstName': 'Bob'}]
```

This seems a bit complicated -- is there a better way to do this?

Comment: "I have the following three dictionaries in an array": there are only 2 dictionaries, and there is no array.

Comment: @ScottHunter thanks for pointing that out -- updated.

Comment: So, everything is merged into a single dict?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ see updated question with an example of what should be merged and what shouldn't.

Comment: Do you want to write a general tool? Or do you want to write a function which is specific to your current data structure?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice either is fine. My issue is mine seems a bit complicated **and** it is very slow -- it's using `deepcopy` two times.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ one additional question: if the field is a List instead of a Set. How would I alter the `lambda` function to add the Lists together into. For example: `.apply(lambda x: set(values1 + values2))`. What would be the correct code for this?

Comment: @David542 Try something like this: `.apply(lambda x: set().union(*x))`... should work for any container. The only difference is `set()` instead of `set`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a couple of ways of doing this. The most painless method to my knowledge utilises the pandas library—in particular, a `groupby` + `apply`.

```
import pandas as pd

merged = (
    pd.DataFrame(items)
      .groupby(['FirstName', 'LastName'], sort=False)
      .Language
      .apply(lambda x: set.union(*x))
      .reset_index()
      .to_dict(orient='records')
)
```

```
print(merged)
[
    {'FirstName': 'David', 'LastName': 'Smith', 'Language': {'en', 'fr'}},
    {'FirstName': 'Bob', 'LastName': 'Jones', 'Language': {'en'}}
]
```

The other method (that I mentioned) uses `itertools.groupby`, but seeing as you have 30 columns to group on, I'd just recommend sticking to pandas.

---

If you want to turn this into a function,

```
def merge(items, field):
    df = pd.DataFrame(items)
    columns = df.columns.difference([field]).tolist()
    return (
        df.groupby(columns, sort=False)[field]
          .apply(lambda x: set.union(*x))
          .reset_index()
          .to_dict(orient='records')
    )
```

```
merged = merge(items, 'Language')
print(merged)
[
    {'FirstName': 'David', 'LastName': 'Smith', 'Language': {'en', 'fr'}},
    {'FirstName': 'Bob', 'LastName': 'Jones', 'Language': {'en'}}
]
```

Comment: Oh this is awesome, I'll check it out. Is there a way to do a `GroupBy` by all fields except for one? Here you're explicitly specifying the GROUP BY fields, but in my actual dict I have about 30 keys and I want to group by everything except the Language field. Is there a short-hard way to do that?

Comment: Great, thank you. I gotta learn this pandas library it seems so cool.

Comment: @COLDSPEED -- also, in regards to your profile: "Grad Student, Data Sciences, USC" -- email me if you're looking for a job: david@premieredigital.net, we are LA-based.

Comment: @David542 I'll likely be looking for full time opportunities this coming fall... let us touch base during that time? Until then, good luck, happy coding, and thanks for the acceptance!

Comment: @COLDSPEED sure, shoot me a quick note via email if you'd be interested in working on any short-term projects ($) while you're in school.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `itertools.groupby`:

```
import itertools
d = [{'FirstName': 'David', 'LastName': 'Smith', 'Language': {'en'}}, {'FirstName': 'David', 'LastName': 'Smith', 'Language': {'fr'}}, {'FirstName': 'Bob', 'LastName': 'Jones', 'Language': {'en'}}]
v = [[a, list(b)] for a, b in itertools.groupby(sorted(d, key=lambda x:x['FirstName']), key=lambda x:x['FirstName'])]
final_dict = [{**{'FirstName':a}, **{'LastName':(lambda x:[list(set(x)), x[0]][len(set(x)) == 1])([i['LastName'] for i in b])}, **{'Language':set([list(i['Language'])[0] for i in b])}} for a, b in v]
```

Output:

```
[{'FirstName': 'Bob', 'LastName': 'Jones', 'Language': {'en'}}, {'FirstName': 'David', 'LastName': 'Smith', 'Language': {'en', 'fr'}}]
```

Comment: [According to OP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50260261/merge-two-dictionaries-based-on-similarity-excluding-a-key/50260457#comment87538902_50260457), this code should work for upto 30 groupers... will this handle that?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ It should, although my first thought for output was instead of a list of dictionaries, a full nested dictionary as a tree structure such as `{'FirstName':'David', 'LastName':{'Smith':{'Languages':{'en'}}}}`, that way, potential multiple `LastNames` could be structured under the same first name, along with each respective language.

Answer (score 1):

If pandas is not an option:

```
from itertools import groupby
from functools import reduce

arr = [
    {'FirstName': 'David', 'LastName': 'Smith', 'Language': set(['en'])},
    {'FirstName': 'David', 'LastName': 'Smith', 'Language': set(['fr'])},
    {'FirstName': 'David', 'LastName': 'Jones', 'Language': set(['sp'])}
]

def reduce_field(items, field, op=set.union, sort=False):

    def _key(d):
        return tuple((k, v) for k, v in d.items() if k != field)

    if sort:
        items = sorted(items, key=_key)
    res = []
    for k, g in groupby(items, key=_key):
        d = dict(k)
        d[field] = reduce(op, (el[field] for el in g))
        res.append(d)

    return res

reduce_field(arr, 'Language')
```

Comment: how would I specify the field I don't want instead of the field I do want in the `groupby` params?

Comment: This was actually the solution I ended up using for implementation -- it requires doing a lot of sorting and postprocessing, etc. and was hard to figure out how to do that all in one call in pandas.

Comment: @David542 BTW, be careful with `itertools.groupby` the array needs to be sorted, (you probably know that).

Comment: @David542 I added a sort option to allow for that

Answer (score 0):

You can try it manually :

```
new_dict={}
#
#
#
d = [{'FirstName': 'David', 'LastName': 'Smith', 'Language': {'en'}},
     {'FirstName': 'David', 'LastName': 'Smith', 'Language': {'fr'}},
     {'FirstName': 'Bob', 'LastName': 'Jones', 'Language': {'en'}}]




for i in d:
     if (i['FirstName'],i['LastName']) not in new_dict:
          new_dict[(i['FirstName'],i['LastName'])]=i
     else:
          new_dict[(i['FirstName'],i['LastName'])]['Language']=set(list(new_dict[(i['FirstName'],i['LastName'])]['Language'])+list(i['Language']))
print(new_dict.values())
```

output:

```
# dict_values([{'FirstName': 'Bob', 
#               'LastName': 'Jones', 
#               'Language': {'en'}}, 
#              {'FirstName': 'David', 
#               'LastName': 'Smith', 
#                'Language': {'fr', 'en'}}])
```